# How to get rvest or sapply to skip NA values?

Tags: r, rvest

I am using `rvest` to (try to) scrape all the author affiliation data from a database of academic publications called RePEc. I have the authors' short IDs (`author_reg`), which I'm using to scrape affiliation data. However, I have several columns indicating multiple authors (each of which I need the affiliation data for). When there aren't multiple authors, the cell has an `NA` value.  Some of the columns are mostly NA values so how do I alter my code so it skips the `NA` values but doesn't delete them?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

df$author_reg <- c("paa6","paa2","paa1", "paa8", "pve266", "pya500", "NA", "NA")

http1 <- "https://ideas.repec.org/e/"
http2 <- "https://ideas.repec.org/f/"

df$affiliation_author_1 <- sapply(df$author_reg_1, function(x) {
  links = c(paste0(http1, x, ".html"),paste0(http2, x, ".html"))

# here we try both links and store under attempts
attempts = links %>% map(function(i){
    try(read_html(i) %>% html_nodes("#affiliation h3") %>% html_text())
  })

# the good ones will have "character" class, the failed ones, try-error
    gdlink = which(sapply(attempts,class) != "try-error")
  if(length(gdlink)>0){
  return(attempts[[gdlink[1]]])
  }
  else{
  return("True 404 error")
  }
})
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see the target links, you can try the following way. First, you want to scrape all links from `https://ideas.repec.org/e/` and create all links. Then, check if each link exists or not. (There are about 26000 links with this URL, and I do not have time to check all. So I just used 100 URLs in the following demonstration.) Extract all existing links.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)

# Get all possible links from this webpage. There are 26665 links.

read_html("https://ideas.repec.org/e/") %>% 
html_nodes("td") %>% 
html_nodes("a") %>% 
html_attr("href") %>% 
.[grepl(x = ., pattern = "html")] -> x

# Create complete URLs.
mylinks1 <- paste("https://ideas.repec.org/e/", x, sep = "")

# For this demonstration I created a subset.
mylinks_samples <- mylinks1[1:100]

# Check if each URL exists or not. If FALSE, a link exists.
foo <- sapply(mylinks_sample, http_error)

# Using the logical vector, foo, extract existing links.
urls <- mylinks_samples[!foo]
```

Then, for each link, I tried to extract affiliation information. There are several spots with `h3`. So I tried to specifically target `h3` that stays in xpath containing `id = "affiliation"`. If there is no affiliation information, R returns `character(0)`. When `enframe()` is applied, these elements are removed. For instance, `pab127` does not have any affiliation information, so there is no entry for this link.

```
lapply(urls, function(x){

    read_html(x, encoding = "UTF-8") %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="affiliation"]') %>%
    html_nodes("h3") %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
    trimws() -> foo

     return(foo)}) -> mylist
```

Then, I assigned names to `mylist` with the links and created a data frame.

```
names(mylist) <- sub(x = basename(urls), pattern = ".html", replacement = "")

enframe(mylist) %>% 
unnest(value)

   name  value                                                                                                       
  <chr> <chr>                                                                                                       
 1 paa1  "(80%) Institutt for ØkonomiUniversitetet i Bergen"                                                         
 2 paa1  "(20%) Gruppe for trygdeøkonomiInstitutt for ØkonomiUniversitetet i Bergen"                                 
 3 paa2  "Department of EconomicsCollege of BusinessUniversity of Wyoming"                                           
 4 paa6  "Statistisk SentralbyråGovernment of Norway"                                                                
 5 paa8  "Centraal Planbureau (CPB)Government of the Netherlands"                                                    
 6 paa9  "(79%) Economic StudiesBrookings Institution"                                                               
 7 paa9  "(21%) Brookings Institution"                                                                               
 8 paa10 "Helseøkonomisk Forskningsprogram (HERO) (Health Economics Research Programme)\nUniversitetet i Oslo (Unive~
 9 paa10 "Institutt for Helseledelse og Helseökonomi (Institute of Health Management and Health Economics)\nUniversi~
10 paa11 "\"Carlo F. Dondena\" Centre for Research on Social Dynamics (DONDENA)\nUniversità Commerciale Luigi Boccon~
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this but I actually have a dataset with about 150,000 entries so I can't just manually assign the entries (and also, I don't know which ones will be https://ideas.repec.org/e/ and which ones will be https://ideas.repec.org/f/. I need to find a way to automate the process so it misses the NA values. Any idea how I might do that?

Comment: @Oliver I revised my suggestion. Have a look. I do not have time to test if all links exist or not. So you gotta check all URLs by yourself. I hope you understand that.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!